# CHECKBOX in CTreeView

Tags: yii

Does anyone knows how to put checkbox in `CTree`?? I already have my `treeview` but I don't know how to put checkbox on it and `return 0 || 1` result.. please help.. Thanks..

```
array("id"=>1,"name"=>"<b>SALES</b>","parents"=>
    array(
        array("id"=>10,"name"=>"<b>Sales Order</b>","parents"=>
            array(
                array("id"=>100,"name"=>"Allow view Transaction PO",
                      array('text' => CHtml::checkBox('name', true)),"parents"

                ),
                array("id"=>101,"name"=>"Allow Click Edit Button PO","parents"

                ),
                array("id"=>101,"name"=>"Allow Click New Button PO","parents"

                ),
                array("id"=>101,"name"=>"Allow Click Save Button PO","parents"

                ),
                array("id"=>101,"name"=>"Allow Click Change Document# PO","parents"

                ),
                array("id"=>101,"name"=>"Allow Click Delete Button PO","parents"

                ),
                array("id"=>101,"name"=>"Allow Click Print Button PO","parents"

                ),
                array("id"=>101,"name"=>"Allow Click Lock Button PO","parents"

                ),
                array("id"=>101,"name"=>"Allow Click Unlock Button PO","parents"

                ),
                array("id"=>101,"name"=>"Un Allow Change Amount PO","parents"

                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

Comment: You mean `CTree` extension or `CTreeView` bundled with yii?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a checkbox in the text property for each element:

```
array(
     ...,
    'text' => CHtml::checkBox('name', true|false) .... 
)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `CTreeView`, but text will escape html? Or not?

Comment: Yes. As it did in text, will add an html checkbox.

Answer (score 3):

Try use [dynatree](http://code.google.com/p/dynatree/)
Create new function for tree: mytree()

```
$(function () {
    $("#tree2").dynatree({
        checkbox: true,
        selectMode: 2,
        children: <?php echo json_encode(Department::model()->mytree(75))?>,
        onSelect: function (select, node) {
            // Display list of selected nodes
            var selNodes = node.tree.getSelectedNodes();
            // convert to title/key array
            var selKeys = $.map(selNodes, function (node) {
                return node.data.ID;
            });
            $("#echoSelection2").text(selKeys.join(", "));
            // $("#departments").val(selKeys.join(", "));
        },
        onClick: function (node, event) {
            // We should not toggle, if target was "checkbox", because this
            // would result in double-toggle (i.e. no toggle)
            if (node.getEventTargetType(event) == "title")
                node.toggleSelect();
        },
        onKeydown: function (node, event) {
            if (event.which == 32) {
                node.toggleSelect();
                return false;
            }
        },
    }
}
```

Html code

```
<div id="tree2" style="max-height: 250px;max-width:300px;overflow:scroll; " class="noshowchecktree controls "></div>
```

Result:
[image]